# How can I display an Image at the JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have a JTable, with custom DefaultTableModel.
I want to insert a ImageIcon into the end column. So I have this code:

```
public class MyTableModelMovimentiContiBancari extends defaultTableModel {

static String[] ColName = { "Cod.","Data","Descrizione", 
    "Codice Spesa","Uscite","Entrate",""};
public LinkedHashMap<Integer,ContoBancarioXOperazione> mappa;

public MyTableModelMovimentiContiBancari() {
    super(ColName, 0);
}

public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return false;
}
public Class<Float> getColumnClass(Float columnIndex) {
    return Float.class;    
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void stampaTabella(List<ContoBancarioXOperazione> mappa,ContoBancario c){
    ImageIcon aboutIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/versamento.png"));
    Double saldoIniziale = c.getSaldoIniziale();
    this.addRow(new Vector());
    super.setValueAt(c.getDataRegistrazioneSaldoFormattata(), this.getRowCount()-1, 1);
    super.setValueAt("SALDO INIZIALE", this.getRowCount()-1, 2);
    super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(saldoIniziale), this.getRowCount()-1, 5);
    for (ContoBancarioXOperazione conto : mappa) {
        int nColumn=0;
        this.addRow(new Vector());
        super.setValueAt(conto.getId().toString(), this.getRowCount()-1, nColumn++);
        super.setValueAt(conto.getDataRegistrazioneFormattata(), this.getRowCount()-1, nColumn++);



        super.setValueAt(conto.getIdSpesa()!=null && conto.getIdSpesa()>0 ? conto.getIdSpesa().toString() :"", this.getRowCount()-1, nColumn++);
        //se c'è stata una spesa l'importo va nell uscita
        if(conto.getIdSpesa()!=null && conto.getIdSpesa()>0){
            super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(conto.getImporto()), this.getRowCount()-1, nColumn++);
            saldoIniziale -=conto.getImporto();
        }

        if(conto.getContoBanarioPrelievo()!=null &&
                conto.getContoBanarioPrelievo().getId()==c.getId()){
            //IN QUESTO CASO L IMPORTO VA NELLE USCITE
            super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(conto.getImporto()), this.getRowCount()-1, 4);
            saldoIniziale -=conto.getImporto();
        }

        //se il movimento non ha spese, non ha conti di prelievo
        //allora significa che è una chiusura di giornata
        if(conto.getIdSpesa()==0 && conto.getContoBanarioPrelievo() == null){
            //IN QUESTO CASO L IMPORTO VA NELLE ENTRATE
            super.setValueAt(decimalFormatter.format(conto.getImporto()), this.getRowCount()-1, 5);
            saldoIniziale +=conto.getImporto();
        }
        super.setValueAt(aboutIcon, this.getRowCount()-1, 6);
    }
}   


}
```

This is the CustomTable that contains my TableMolde

```
package com.mcsolution.table.MioJTable;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

import com.mcsolution.table.MioTableModel.MyTableModelMovimentiContiBancari;

public class CustomTableMovimentiConti extends JTable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1180088009825388637L;
    private Font myFontTotale= new Font("Century Gothic", Font.BOLD, 17);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private MyTableModelMovimentiContiBancari modello;   // Sarà un riferimento al TableModel
    public CustomTableMovimentiConti(MyTableModelMovimentiContiBancari tableModel) {
        super(tableModel);
        modello = tableModel;
    }

    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {

        Component rendererComponent = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

        if(row==0){
            rendererComponent.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
            rendererComponent.setFont(myFontTotale);
        }else if(row == super.getRowCount()-1){
            if(super.getValueAt(row, 2)!=null && 
                    super.getValueAt(row, 2).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("SALDO FINALE")){
                //ultima riga
                rendererComponent.setBackground(new Color(200, 200, 200));
                rendererComponent.setFont(myFontTotale);
            }           
        }else{
            rendererComponent.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
        return rendererComponent;
    }
}
```

With this code, I don't have any error but instead of the show the image at the end column I see the full path.

Comment: The "last" column should return `Icon.class` and the last column should have a `Icon` as the data value...

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [How to use tables, Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), the default renderers are capable of handling `Icon` or `ImageIcon` objects.

You `getColumnClass` method from your `TableModel` needs to return either `Icon.class` or `ImageIcon.class` for the appropriate column and the `TableModel` needs to back it with the correct data for that column

Comment: I have change the method getColumnClass in MyTableModel class. So I have this now:
public Class<ImageIcon> getColumnClass(ImageIcon columnIndex) {
  return ImageIcon.class;    // Le due colonne sono numeri interi
 }
but not works

Comment: You need to return a different type based on each column, as not all you columns are icons...